# Displaying Google Maps and OpenStreetMap map in Java?

Tags: openlayers-2, java, geotools

Is there any Java API that is like OpenLayers ?

I would like to display google Maps and Openlayers Maps in a java application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

http://weblogs.java.net/blog/cajo/archive/2010/10/16/adding-google-maps-your-java-application

You can also use [Bing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa907674.aspx) maps with Java, also worth looking at

- [GeoTools](http://www.geotools.org/)
- [NASA Worldwind](http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/)
- [OpenMap](http://openmap.bbn.com/)

There's also a useful list of OpenSource Java GIS software here: http://java-source.net/open-source/geospatial

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [GWT-openlayers](https://bitbucket.org/gwtopenlayers/) a GWT wrapper for OpenLayers, or [Geomajas](http://geomajas.org) a full-blown framework for building GIS web applications.

Answer (score 1):

I found also another interesting library : [uDig](http://udig.refractions.net/)